# Can't run a simple 'hello world' app

Tags: android

When I'm trying to run the app, it says:
Unable to locate `adb`

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

I've read a lot of posts regarding the missing `adb.exe` file and the adb.exe simply does not exist in the path `.../platform-tools/adb.exe`

how can I get it/fix it?

Comment: what is your operating system ?

Comment: Did you install the android sdk platform-tools? See in android studio `Tools>Android>SDK-Manager>SDK Tools`

Answer (score 0):

The adb.exe file will be located at your Android SDK folder, inside platform-tools

```
...\android-sdk-path\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

The default location where Android SDK is installed is:

```
C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
```

So adb will be located at:

```
C:\Users\<insert username here>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

adb is Android Debug Bridge tool that stays in Android/SDK/platform-tools directory.....
If ADB is missing you can download from this link
[Platform tools by Google for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select/install the Android SDK Platform-tools.
Go to `Tools > Android SDK platform tools`.
After doing this, try to build again. It should work.

If the above does not solve the problem, try reinstalling the tools: open the "Standalone SDK manager" and uninstall the Android SDK platform-tools, delete the `[your sdk directory]/platform-tools` directory completely and install it again using the SDK manager.

Hope this helps!